# Grails 5 app builds successfully but does not run

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, grails

I'm in the process of upgrading a Grails 4.0.x app to Grails 5.3.0. I have managed to get the app building, however, the app itself does not start.

Gradle goes through the actionable tasks and when it executes the `:bootRun` task, it exits with code 0 and terminates without running the app.

I have tried both IntelliJ and gradlew (command line). Gradle has been upgraded to 7.2 and JDK to version 11. I've tried Spring Boot 2.5, 2.6 and 2.7.
I've generated a blank grails 5 app, used the same versions, compared build.gradle files and the blank one runs fine.

Command line:

```
C:\Code\project>gradlew.bat bootRun

> Task :bootRun
         @@@@@@@@@@@
      @@             @@
    @                   @
  @@                      @          @@@@@@@@@@@@   @@@@@@@@@@@@        @@@@@@@      @@@@   @@@@        @@@@@@@@@@
 @    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    @      @@@@@@@@# 8@@@    @@@@    @@@@@      @@@@@@@@      @@@@   @@@@      @@@@@@  @@@
 @    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@o    #@    @@@@@              @@@@     @@@@@     @@@@ @@@@     @@@@   @@@@      @@@@
@  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @@@@  @    @@@@               @@@@     @@@@     @@@@  @@@@@    @@@@   @@@@      @@@@@@@
@   @@@@  @@@@@@@@@ @@@@@   @   @@@@@      @@@@@@@  @@@@@@@@@@@@      @@@@   @@@@    @@@@   @@@@        @@@@@@@@@
@      @@    @@@   :@@      @   @@@@@       @@@@@@  @@@@@@@@@@@      @@@@    @@@@@   @@@@   @@@@           @@@@@@@
.@     @@    @@@    @@     &@    @@@@@       @@@@@  @@@@    @@@@    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@   @@@@   @@@@              @@@@@
 @     @@@   @@@   @@@     @     @@@@@@      @@@@@  @@@@    @@@@@   @@@@      @@@@@  @@@@   @@@@              @@@@@
  @@        @@@@@         @        @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  @@@@     @@@@@ @@@@@       @@@@@ @@@@   @@@@@@@@@  @@@@@@@@@@@
    @                   @             @@@@@@@@@@8   @@@@      @@@@ @@@@        @@@@@ @@@@   @@@@@@@@@  @@@@@@@@@
      @@             @@
         @@@@@@@@@@@


Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 41s
9 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 5 up-to-date
C:\Code\project>
```

IntelliJ:

```
|Running application...
> Task :bootBuildInfo
> Task :flywayMigrate
> Task :generateJooq UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileGroovy
> Task :buildProperties
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes
> Task :bootRunMainClassName

> Task :bootRun
         @@@@@@@@@@@                                                                                              
      @@             @@                                                                                           
    @                   @                                                                                         
  @@                      @          @@@@@@@@@@@@   @@@@@@@@@@@@        @@@@@@@      @@@@   @@@@        @@@@@@@@@@
 @    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    @      @@@@@@@@# 8@@@    @@@@    @@@@@      @@@@@@@@      @@@@   @@@@      @@@@@@  @@@ 
 @    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@o    #@    @@@@@              @@@@     @@@@@     @@@@ @@@@     @@@@   @@@@      @@@@        
@  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @@@@  @    @@@@               @@@@     @@@@     @@@@  @@@@@    @@@@   @@@@      @@@@@@@     
@   @@@@  @@@@@@@@@ @@@@@   @   @@@@@      @@@@@@@  @@@@@@@@@@@@      @@@@   @@@@    @@@@   @@@@        @@@@@@@@@ 
@      @@    @@@   :@@      @   @@@@@       @@@@@@  @@@@@@@@@@@      @@@@    @@@@@   @@@@   @@@@           @@@@@@@
.@     @@    @@@    @@     &@    @@@@@       @@@@@  @@@@    @@@@    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@   @@@@   @@@@              @@@@@
 @     @@@   @@@   @@@     @     @@@@@@      @@@@@  @@@@    @@@@@   @@@@      @@@@@  @@@@   @@@@              @@@@@
  @@        @@@@@         @        @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  @@@@     @@@@@ @@@@@       @@@@@ @@@@   @@@@@@@@@  @@@@@@@@@@@
    @                   @             @@@@@@@@@@8   @@@@      @@@@ @@@@        @@@@@ @@@@   @@@@@@@@@  @@@@@@@@@  
      @@             @@                                                                                           
         @@@@@@@@@@@                                                                                              


Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2m 41s
9 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 3 up-to-date

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Is there anything I should be looking for or ways I can debug the bootRun task to figure out why this is happening.
Has anyone come across this situation before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, there was no stdout logger defined. I found the file log buried in some obscure location (log config was brought in from another app) and found it was hitting an error and exiting.